# Adding "view all" subcategory to all top menu's categories

Tags: magento-1.9, module, topmenu

I'm working in a default/default theme in Magento 1.9.3.2.
I would like to make a custom module that adds to categories of products(placed at the top menu) new subcategory called "View All" that displays all products from a given category, i.e.: 
Category: Woman 
Before:
    Subcategories: New Arrivals, Tops & Blouses, Pants & Denim, Dresses & 
    Skirts
    After:
Subcategories: View all, New Arrivals, Tops & Blouses, 
    Pants & Denim, Dresses & Skirts.

I have got a very similar problem to this one: [How to make "view all" link in topmenu with sub categories](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33141/how-to-make-view-all-link-in-topmenu-with-sub-categories) but I don't really know how to approach this problem anyway.

What steps (starting from scratch) should I take to achieve my goal? 
I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take help from below file:

**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml**

By default, **`View All`** functionality has been added into **`RWD theme`** of Magento. Since Magento team did not want to change layout of default theme, it introduced a completely new responsive theme known as RWD.

Please check code like below in renderer.phtml file and make changes in file of default theme accordingly:

```
if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
        $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
        $html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel .' view-all">';
        $html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';
        $html .=             $this->__('View All') . ' ' . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
        $html .=         '</a>';
        $html .=     '</li>';
        $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }
```

Please let me know if you find any problem.