# Add "View More" Functionality in Mega Menu

Tags: magento-1.9

I have "bizarre magento theme". theme have mega menu default.client want to add "view more" functionality in that. for better understand see below image[image]

From Above image you can see brands category, client want to display 5-6 category in the sub category and "view more" functionality. If user click on "view more" than display all the category in the same way display like image.

Any Kind of help will appreciate.
Magento Version:`1.9.3.4`

`topmenu.phtml` file

```
<?php
$_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top');
$menuStatus = Mage::getStoreConfig('meigee_categoriesenhanced/options/status');
if ($menuStatus == 1) {
    $navAttr = 'class="nav-wide"';
}
else {
    $navAttr = 'class="nav"';
}

?>
<nav class="nav-container">
    <ul <?php echo $navAttr; ?>>
    <?php echo $_menu; ?>
    <!--<li class="level0 nav-1 first level-top"><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>contact" class="level-top" style=""><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>-->
    <!--<li class="level0 nav-1 first level-top"><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>catalogsearch/result/?brand=25" class="level-top" style=""><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>-->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

here is my `topmenu` file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a data-toggle of collapse type.

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/amir_prince/cou3dwta/)

Comment: Hey Prince thanks for reply , I added `topmenu` file , can you please tell me where to put condition for view more functionality

Comment: and also I want to view more link under  brands->subcategory->subcategory

Comment: then I want to put view more link